# How heroku handles web traffic and distribute among dyno

Tags: heroku, dyno

I want to know how heroku handles incoming web traffic and distribute among dynos. How Heroku knows when to distribute. Can one dyno handle many request at same time?

Comment: This is not a programming question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I didnt know where to post this. @quant

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Heroku's [routing documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing).

Specifically, for your question about dynos handling multiple requests, yes, Heroku will route multiple requests to the same dyno. Some servers may not handle multiple ones though. For example, the default ruby server, Webrick doesn't. You'd have to use puma to have several threads, one handling each request.